# Why MediaPlayer prepare() is not to be used with streams?

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

The docs for `MediaStream`'s method `prepareAsync()` says:

> Prepares the player for playback, asynchronously. After setting the
>   datasource and the display surface, you need to either call prepare()
>   or prepareAsync(). **For streams, you should call prepareAsync(),
>   which returns immediately**, rather than blocking until enough data
>   has been buffered.

What **bad can go wrong** if we use `prepare()` for playing streams? I've been using `prepare()` and I never got into any troubles.

On contrary, in my own case, when I **use 'prepareAsync()'**, the stream does NOT start ever. When I **use 'prepare()'** the stream starts after buffering period (1s-2s) and plays well. Why is this happening with async method? Is the form for async prepare the same as for `prepare()`?

```
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
    mPlayer.prepareAsync();
    mPlayer.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing complex operations in the UI thread is a bad practice. It can block your UI for a long time and Android may kill your app.
In this case, the prepare() method can take a lot of time due to decoding and fetching data.

You should call the prepareAsync() method while listening the OnPrepared event. When the event is triggered you should notify your UI and start the player.

```
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mPlayer.setDataSource(STREAM_URL);
mplayer.setOnPreparedListener(/*your listener here*/)
mPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `prepare()` is that it blocks the `UI` thread. If it takes too long to prepare the media, your app will be killed with an `ANR` error.

Event then, blocking the `UI` thread for 1 to 2 seconds isn't exactly cool. If you're hitting a web server, you're going to get killed sooner or later, for sure.

To get `prepareAsync` to work, You have to call `MediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener`, and then call `MediaPlayer.start()` in the handler.